# How to move db to ds in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

If I have a string like this

```
test db "Test", 0
```

How can I move this to the `DS` register in x86 assembly (For example to print the chars) ?
This would be wrong:

```
mov ax, test
mov ds, ax
```

Comment: What assembler are you using?

Comment: If you are using MASM, try `mov ax, SEG test`.

Comment: I use nasm for this

Comment: What exactly do you want your code to assemble to?  Assuming this is 16-bit real mode, do you want `ds:0` to be the address of `test` afterwards (assuming `test` is 16-byte aligned)?  If not, what way of addressing `test` do you want to work afterwards?

Comment: Ummm... Why would you ever want to move the location of a piece of data into DS...???

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is to print the characters of the string, then it would be the **offset** of *test* that you would need. The setup of the `DS` and `ES` segment registers would have been delt with early in the program setup.

```
segment data
    test db "Test", 0

segment code
    mov     ax, data
    mov     ds, ax
    mov     es, ax

    ...

    mov     bx, test    ;Put offset address of the string in BX register
    mov     dl, [bx+2]  ;Read 3rd character of the string
    mov     ah, 02h     ;DOS.DisplayCharacter
    int     21h
```